# Flutter web build takes more than 30 minutes

Tags: flutter

```
[+994194 ms] file:///home/desktop-pc/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/widget_inspector.dart:291:11:
Hint: Overriding 'noSuchMethod' causes the compiler to generate more code and prevents the compiler from doing some optimizations.
Consider removing this 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

dynamic noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) {
```

I build the flutter web app with `flutter build web -vv` and it took nearly an hour to finish to build the app.

What is the cause of this error? Was it caused by my code or the flutter framework?

How to fix it?

I looked for missing method but failed to find any on my code.